# How to split a network of polylines and then extract vertices without having overlapping lines?

Tags: network, nodes, splitting

I tried to split polylines with GRASS or QGIS tools but I obtain always a layer with overlapping lines. I figured it out because I always make a spatial join between the splitted lines and the nodes in order to have a table of edges defined by the min and max nodes.

How to avoid overlapping lines/edges?

Comment: Could you provide a sample file with your desided output?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it thanks to v.net.iso, it seems to be the only tool which can avoid creation of overlapping edges/nodes. Firstly I extract vertices, then I deleted duplicates of them and then I used v.net.iso.